# How to render Angular Templating / Handlebars into injected HTML bound by innerHTML - Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some content in a serperate file like so (see below), basically I have a lot of HTML, that contains Angular templating.

```
export var DataProtectionHtml: string = `<a href="{{windowLocation}}#section1">Go to Section 1</a></li>`;
```

I import the exported variable it into a Componenet. I then assign a component property to the exported variable, sanitize it with the Angular DomSanitizer and then bind it into my HTML template using [innerHTML], here is the component and template code (I have reduced the code for clarity)

```
import * as dpHtml from './terms-conditions-text/data-protection.text';

windowLocation: string;
htmlContent: string;

constructor(private location: Location, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

    this.windowLocation = location.prepareExternalUrl(location.path()); // let's say this is "/legal/terms-conditions"
    this.htmlContent = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(dpHtml.DataProtectionHtml);
}
```

here is the template...

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlContent"></div>
```

Now the rendered page doesn't bind the value `this.windowLocation`to the injected HTML. The anchor link when rendered treats {{windowLocation}} as a string, how can I get it to output the content so the Angular Templating works. So my link would point to "/legal/terms-conditions#section1"?

I do realise that I could just use a `replace`method, but I am unsure if this is the best way, for example:

```
this.htmlContent = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(dpHtml.DataProtectionHtml.replace('{{windowLocation}}', this.windowLocation));
```

I am sorry if I haven't explained myself well here, if so, please say so and I shall rewrite my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: `{{}}` is only processed when statically added to a components template. This is not what you are doing, therefore this won't work. Same for event binding and `[]`.